# how can I get or set custom appsetting.json with c#

Tags: c#, json

```
[{
    "Group": " ",
    "Key": "Sender:StoreType",
    "Value": "ExchangeStack.Stores.Rabbit.RabbitStore,ExchangeStack.Stores.Rabbit",
    "Description": "存储器（发送） 不用改"
}, {
    "Group": " ",
    "Key": "Receiver:StoreType",
    "Value": "ExchangeStack.Stores.Rabbit.RabbitStore,ExchangeStack.Stores.Rabbit",
    "Description": "存储器（接收）不用改"
}, {
    "Group": " ",
    "Key": "Sender:BatchSize",
    "Value": 1000,
    "Description": "一次发送的数量"
}]
```

How can I get or set the Description (Or Value)'s value by key's value?
The configuration file format is generated by other programs and is already running, and I am not able to change its structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume, you have a class, that represents your config:

```
public class MyConfig
{
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Let's furthe assume, your array of `MyConfig` is stored in your appsettings.json like this:

```
{
    "MyConfig": [
        {
            "Group": " ",
            "Key": "Sender:StoreType",
            "Value": "ExchangeStack.Stores.Rabbit.RabbitStore,ExchangeStack.Stores.Rabbit",
            "Description": "存储器（发送） 不用改"
        },
        { ... }
    ]
}
```

You can get your values like this:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
var config = builder.Build();
//Get the section
var cfg = config.GetSection("MyConfig")
//and bind it to your strongly typed object
                .Get<MyConfig[]>();
//iterate over it
foreach(var item in cfg) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key} --- {item.Value}");
}
```

Output:

```
Sender:StoreType --- ExchangeStack.Stores.Rabbit.RabbitStore,ExchangeStack.Stores.Rabbit
Receiver:StoreType --- ExchangeStack.Stores.Rabbit.RabbitStore,ExchangeStack.Stores.Rabbit
Sender:BatchSize --- 1000
```

As to your problem, with writing the settings back: You can simply overwrite the setting with `cfg[0].Value`, but this does only update the in memory representation of your config, not the file itself. You can of course write that to the json file yourself if you so desire, but I'd suggest, you store your config in a database of some sorts, and plug your own configuration provider for this, as it would make reading and writing back your changes much easier and more centralized, if you ever scale out.

Comment: Just a call out that `Get<>` requires a reference to [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder) which may or may not already be transitively referenced depending on the context.

Comment: Unfortunately, it cannot contain section content and needs to maintain its original structure

Comment: Of course, but you **must** give it a name, even the top-level object in a json document, is an `object`, so your array must be an object property, that must have a name.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string targetDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\AppSetting.json";
        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(targetDir, Encoding.Default);
        jsonString = "{\"MyConfig\":" + jsonString.Replace("\r\n", "") + "}";
        IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonStream(new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString))).AddEnvironmentVariables();
        IConfigurationRoot config = builder.Build();
        MyConfig[] cfg = config.GetSection("MyConfig").Get<MyConfig[]>();
```

Thanks you @Marco